# Writing to multiple instances of HTML tag with JavaScript only writes to first tag

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I need some help trying to figure out what's out on here.  I have a HTML document that I'm setting up for printing, but the page counter is giving me a headache.  Here's the code that's giving me issues:

```html
<html>
 <head>
  <style type="text/css">
   .page {
    width: 8in;
    height: 1in;
    padding: 0em;
    margin-top: .5in;
    margin-left: 0in;
    margin-right: 0in;
    margin-bottom: 0.25in;
   }
   body {
    color: black;
                counter-reset: pagen;
    font-family: "Courier New", Courier, monospace;
    font-size: 10pt;
   }
   .footer {
    counter-increment: pagen;
    margin: auto;
    width: 8in;
    display: table;
   }
   #footer-left:before {
    content: "Page " counter(pagen) " of ";
   }
   .ptable {
    page-break-before: always;
    page-break-inside: avoid;
   }
  </style>
 </head>
 <body>
  <div class="page">
   <div class="footer">
    <div id="footer-left"><span id="total"></span></div>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="page">
   <table class="ptable"></table>
   <div class="footer">
    <div id="footer-left"><span id="total"></span></div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </body>
 <script type ="text/javascript">
  function pageCount() {
   return document.getElementsByClassName('page').length;
  }
  document.getElementById("total").innerHTML = pageCount();
 </script>
</html>
```

The first instance of `footer-left` will output correctly as `Page 1 of 2`.  The second instance displays only `Page 2 of`.  What is going on here?  For reference, I'm setting this document up to be automatically generated by a VBA script based on a query output, so depending on how big the query is the total page count could change: cover page + data page(s).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have duplicate `id` attribute which is not valid, use class attribute instead, also use [document.querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll)() to select the elements, here is a working snippet:

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <style type="text/css">
            .page {
                width: 8in;
                height: 1in;
                padding: 0em;
                margin-top: .5in;
                margin-left: 0in;
                margin-right: 0in;
                margin-bottom: 0.25in;
            }
            body {
                color: black;
                counter-reset: pagen;
                font-family: "Courier New", Courier, monospace;
                font-size: 10pt;
            }
            .footer {
                counter-increment: pagen;
                margin: auto;
                width: 8in;
                display: table;
            }
            #footer-left:before {
                content: "Page " counter(pagen) " of ";
            }
            .ptable {
                page-break-before: always;
                page-break-inside: avoid;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="page">
            <div class="footer">
                <div id="footer-left"><span class="total"></span></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="page">
            <table class="ptable"></table>
            <div class="footer">
                <div id="footer-left"><span class="total"></span></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
    <script type ="text/javascript">
        function pageCount() {
            return document.getElementsByClassName('page').length;
        }
        document.querySelectorAll(".total").forEach(function(el, i){
         el.innerHTML = pageCount();     
        });
        
    </script>
</html>
```

Comment: When I copied this back into the file and ran it in Chrome, it's not generating the total count for either page now.

Comment: @Chaosbydesign, fixed it, check it now.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem would be highlighted if you had [used a validator](https://validator.nu/).

An `id` must be **unique** within a document.

Error recovery means that `getElementById` gets the first match.

Use a `class` if you want a *group* of elements instead of uniquely identifying a single element.

Comment: I will definitely be adding that validator to my toolbox.